# Is there a way to match npm linked projects git branches?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs

Say I have two private (not available through npm) projects: projectA and projectB, both using Git as repos:

ProjectA:

- Main project
- Javascript, ES6, JSX, etc..
- Uses Webpack for build, minification, etc.
- Is compiled with Babel
- **Includes Babel compiled ProjectB repo/branch in package.json**

ProjectB:

- Javascript, ES6, a **dependency of ProjectA**
- Is compiled with Babel into ES5 compatible JS

On my local environment these projects are linked using `npm link` and on build environment ProjectB is fetched from the git repo by ProjectA.

What I want to achieve: sync git branches when building (Babel/Webpack) projectA, e.g.:while building  ProjectA **dev** branch to fetch **dev** branch of ProjectB.

As package.json cannot have any other name the only option that comes to mind is shell scripting (looking up and replacing the branch name of projectB in package.json of projectA based on git branch).

But maybe there's a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with bash scripts: before the build of projectA executing this:

```
sed -i -e "s/projectB\.git.*/projectB\.git#$BRANCH\",/g" ./package.json
```

This changes project's B branch  to `$BRANCH` which holds the value of the project'a A branch at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

NPM linking is used for development purposes so you can write one module while testing it against another module. For example, writing a plugin for Express. You should only link temporarily to do this sort of work. The rest of the time you should be using actual `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

To lock version dependencies between modules, you should be using packages from git. These can be targeted using specific commit hashes or tags. Be sure to use [semver](http://semver.org/) notation with your tags since that's what npm expects.

Comment: It's all true, but not really what I was asking - I guess there's no solution to my problem.